# Woocommerce reuse values in variable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I hope someone can help me with this :)

I will be selling a product that has 10 variables, but all the choices need to be the same for all, how can I add and reuse the values once instead of copying and pasting values 10 times?

What I will be selling is a 10 meal bulk package and each meal needs the
same choice values.

[Picture of what I'm trying to achieve here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61411490/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-10%20at%2020.07.27.png)

Thanks for any help in advance :) Scott

Comment: Once you save attribute terms (for example: Small, Medium, Large, XL, in a "size" attribute) you won't have to retype those terms, but you would need to re-select the size attribute and the associated terms. Currently, I think the best bet would be to configure one product with all the variations/attributes you need and then duplicate that product and edit the rest of the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 different products, 5 meals, 7 meals and 10 meals in which the customer can choose their own meals, the attribute values will also be changing weekly.  which at the moment I am pasting in new values 22 times in the edit product.

If I delete and duplicate the product I lose the URL

When I go to Products > attributes still the same making 10 attributes like meal 1, meal 2, meal 3 etc I can't duplicate them and have to do it all manually up to 40 times with new values.

[Picture Front end here]

(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61411490/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-17%20at%2009.33.32.png).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but I have encountered the same issue and my solution might be of interest to the next person who happens on this question.

I am using [WP All Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/) and [the Woocommerce extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/) (both free, but variable products require a license) to maintain product details in excel. Updating data on the website is as easy as uploading a new CSV. Keeping data in sync in an excel file, with references, formulas, etc. becomes much easier, and you can often completely factor out duplicate data.

Instead of using Woocommerce's variable products, I created each version as a simple product and linked between them.